# for networking guys..how to backup server

Tags: backup, windows-server-2008

new to this..in the process of learning how to do this on my own...
have two servers in different office locations, a few questions..
background info:
- around 70GB of contents on the server needs to be backed up, ocassionally..or whenever files are updated 
- around 800MB are the databases that needs to be backed up daily..
- the rest can be backed up less frequently 
- we want to make sure if one server room burns down/flood, etc..we still have a backup copy at another location...
-running on  windows servers
what is the best way to do this?
i have a fibre line...upload speed is good...
how would the following suggestions work
a) can I just backup the servers files in the two cities to their counterpart through the internet? If so, is there a good program that can automatically do the backup? office a gets copied to office b server, vice versa
b) if not, what services should i use that will allow automatic backup /sync..it will be better if they only sync when the files get updated/changed / incrementally...via what means? Azure? Amazon cloud?
c) or backups would take too long, i should  just copy it to an external driver everyday and take it home ?
d) or need to use some IT services that specifically do server backups..

what's a ballpark figure on the cost of these options...

just want good suggests from professionals..want a method that's dependable and not expensive...thanks guys/gals

Comment: This site isn't meant for questions that would be opinion based (like what the best backup method would be) or for what things might cost. If you had a specific technical question about how a particular backup scenario would work and you had started in on the processes already and hit a kink - by all means, ask that sort of question - but as you have it posed, this is considered off-topic.

Comment: When you say database, do you mean SQL? Either way, there are automatic backup options to generate backups for you. When they go into their backup directory, you can sync the files using (tool) WinSCP to Amazon S3 storage for pricing of about ` First 50 TB/ month $0.023 / GB ` etc. There are many options but this is an easy suggestion if you are backing up infrequently or storing only a few backups at a time in a rotation.